# Does PHP variables automatically removed from the memory once move to next page (garbage collection)?

Tags: php, variables, garbage-collection

Looked around but couldn't find any single post on this topic anywhere on the web.
My question is about PHP variable that we use to store values mostly user inputs or database values in our variables such as

```
$firstname = tableClass->firstname; //or
$firstname = $_POST['username'];
```

Or the connection handler of the database, what I am trying to ask here is doesnt matter what type will i have to set them manually i.e. `$firstname=null` or `$connection=null` or it just automatically removed from the memory once page is changed?

This is because in java process of de-allocating memory is handled automatically by the garbage collector. whereas in a programming language like C, allocating and de-allocating memory is a manual process.

Any idea?

Comment: Each execution of a PHP script is a one-off: it loads everything it needs, it executes, it terminates and all memory it used is freed. There is no persistence of data between requests unless it is manually implemented

Comment: You didnt look hard enough: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php